# Python: automate typing in fields inside a pop-up window on an open browser

Tags: python

Python users, I am editing this post to make it clearer what I am seeking to do. I have attached an image (hope this is visible to other established users as I do not have picture uploading privileges) of what it looks like on the website I am using.
Basically, after I log into the website and select what kind of data I would like to retrieve, I am faced with a screen with several buttons, one of them being an Excel button to download the data in excel format. When I click on the Excel button, a pop up comes over the page as per the attached picture. This pop up is fixed on the screen (I cannot move it, but if I click outside of it, it disappears and leaves me with the webpage prior to clicking the Excel button). From that pop-up window, under the pulldown menu "For which companies?" I need to select "A range of companies" What I then need to do is to delete the text under the "Name:" field and enter a different name, e.g. name 1. And then in the "from" field, I need to enter 1 and in the "to" field, I need to enter 47619. Then I need to click on the "Export" button. On clicking the "Export" button, this instructs the database to download the data for these 47619 companies in the background. Then I repeat the process, i.e. Name: name2, from: 47620, to: 95238, Export, and so on. My downloads are in increments of 47619 observations and my name patterns will be name1,name2,name3....name117. This is the reason I am seeking to automate the above in a loop that follows the above naming structure and index counter increment of 47619 for each data download.

Once I finish, I will repeat all of the above 200 times (i.e. 200 x 117) so you can understand my interest in automating this.

[webpage_example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHrDY.png)

What I have done so far is to find the co-ordinates to that Excel clickable button and get pyautogui to click on that button - that worked fine. What I don't know how to do now is once the pop-up window comes up, to fill in the fields as well as pull the drop-down menu and make a selection there). I searched the coordinates for say the "Name:" field and wanted to type into it but it is not responding. Please see what I have written so far (very basic) but I am not clear how to proceed. Someone suggested locateonscreen, I looked into that and tried to match a cut out picture from printscreen on the window, but I was not successful with that. I would very much welcome any ideas on this please and thank you in advance for your insights on this. Code follows below:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard, time

#makes program execution pause for 5 sec - to give us a chance to click the open 
#window of interest 
time.sleep(5) 
pyautogui.position()

#excel button coordinates
pyautogui.click(x=1577,y=208)

#these are the co-ordinates on the pop-up window I want to type into 
#but it appears these are the same co-ordinates as the actual browser window and
#this is not doing anything
pyautogui.click(946,298);pyautogui.write('Hello world!')
```

Comment: Have you tried the locateonscreen function from pyautogui?

Comment: So from my understanding... you need the code to download an EXCEL archive? A link from the site would be helpful

Comment: I edited my OP to provide more clarification on what I am seeking to do in Python. Apologies, I am unable to provide a link to the webpage - it is a commercial subscription only database and in any case would require a login and further click choices to get to the  data view that I am seeking to extract using automation codes in Python. I would also like to clarify that the login process is Shibboleth authentication and I was unable to do this with Selenium in Python as this is beyond my expertise. I therefore logged in manually and got the point when I want to automate the downloads.

Comment: Are you familiar with how web browsers work? If you can find the endpoint where the data is served you might be able to get it from there. If its protected by a login it can add some steps to make this happen but not impossible. I can think of almost no reasons  why you should ever have to write a python script to click things in a web browser.

Comment: I don't think the database service allows mass data extraction via the method that you have in mind (did you mean some form of backend integration?). I tried Selenium in Python to try to automate this (by locating elements on the webpage and referring to these) but I got stuck at the login process (Shibboleth login) . But then I am not very well-versed with this and thought perhaps I could handle this via pyautogui...

Comment: If it's a website it almost certainly does. Your web browser makes http requests to web servers and then downloads the file or displays a web page based on the request. There is a URL somewhere where the input data (the things in the form) are submitted to. You can submit the same data to the same place using any modern programming language or 3rd party http programs to get the same result. You can maybe get the endpoint in network -> xhr tab of developer tools in your browser, but if you're not familiar with that it might not be so straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions Joel M - I catch what you are saying but programming this is beyond my capabilities and I would probably not want to go down that route. Hopefully someone may be able to suggest a solution based on pyautogui or another simple alternative but it this is not possible, then I will have to resort to manual downloads. Thank you all for your contributions to this post.

Comment: Python users, I have now found a ready-made solution to the above via Katalon. I am using it's web browser add-on which allows you to record your mouse and keyboard actions on an already opened browser, with the option to translate these into codes in Python and other programming languages. I modified these codes to introduce a loop to match what I was trying to do and this is working. Thank you all for your contributions to this post.